# How to configure web.xml to serve any request without specifying .html, .json in the URL

Tags: javascript, json, xml, spring

I have a javaScript function in my Spring application which use to serve a REST GET call.

```
function populateCombo(){
$.ajax({
      url: "activities.json",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log("data from AJAX : "+data);
      //$('#activities').html(html);
    });
}
```

And I have configured my `web.xml` to cater that request.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But is there anyway to achieve this same result without having to call the url in ajax as `activities.json`
i.e. something like this ,

```
function populateCombo(){
$.ajax({
      url: "activities",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log("data from AJAX : "+data);
      //$('#activities').html(html);
    });
}
```

my web.xml is,

```
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note : I tried to  achieve this by removing all the  and adding the below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but then it showing an error for my javaScript file imports

ex : `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FitnessTracker/resources/javaScript/jquery/jquery.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'fitTrackerServlet'`

in jsp file it is imported as,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/FitnessTracker/resources/javaScript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about using of

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is correct. But Spring doesn't know that jquery.js is a static resource and it tries to find an appropriate RequestMapping for the requested URL. Use this tag

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
```

in your Spring application context to mark all paths to static resources.